# Installing TaskCat using docker, and running taskCat errors out bash: taskcat: command not found

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation

After installing docker successfully, and installing taskCat using docker,

$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-quickstart/taskcat/master/installer/docker-installer.sh | sh

When i run the below command
$ taskcat -c /ci/taskcat.yml

I get an error 
"bash: taskcat: command not found"

Comment: It may help to include the command you used to install taskcat. The problem here is clearly that either 1.) you did not in fact install taskcat, or 2.) bash doesn't know *where* you installed taskcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `whereis taskcat`, or use the `find` command or `locate` command to find  the install location of the taskcat command.
The path variable for taskcat has not been setup, that maybe a reason why it says command not found.

Some commands get installed in the homedirectory/bin folder, this path is not included by default in the PATH variable.
You can do `export PATH=$PATH:/home/myuserdir/bin` to solve this issue.